# Writing \t, line feed and carriage return to windows event log from a windows service

Tags: vb.net, event-log

I have a windows service built in .NET and VB.NET. I am writing logs to windows event log but I am not able to write \t, line feed and carriage return to it.

I have a string like below:

```
Dim myMessage As String = "Parameters read: \n\n"
myMessage += "\t\tParamA: " + paramA
myMessage += "\t\tParamB: " + paramB
```

Log is written to event log but \t and \n are not applied. It appears as a single line string:

> "Parameters read: \n\n\t\tParamA: 2\t\tParamB: 4"

I have tried %t instead of \t and %n instead of \n and it is not working:

```
Dim myMessage As String = "Parameters read: %n%n"
myMessage += "%t%tParamA: " + paramA
myMessage += "%t%tParamB: " + paramB
```

To write to event log I do below:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(myMessage, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information, 1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be using the `ControlChars` class and its `Tab`, `Cr`, `Lf` and `CrLf` properties. They are part of the VB.NET Runtime specifically because VB doesn't support C-style escape sequences like C# does.